# ag-Grid: use floatingBottomRowData when Pivoting

Tags: pivot-table, ag-grid

I'm trying to recreate the following pivot table with ag-Grid:
[image]

Using floatingBottomRowData I can't find a way to pass the values for all generated columns. so one pair of values is getting duplicated:
[image]

My goal is to access the column group value for each cell of the floating row.
Right now I can't tell the difference between column groups (resulting in duplicated values).

Is there any way to differentiate the different (col1, col2) pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer that was given in the ag-grid forum is:

to get the pivot key, do this:

```
floatingCellRenderer: function(params) {
        if (gridOptions.columnApi.isPivotMode()) {
            console.log(params.column.getId());
            var parent = params.column.getParent();
            if (parent) {
                var pivotKey = console.log(parent.getOriginalColumnGroup().getColGroupDef().pivotKeys[0]);
            }    
        }
    }
```

to get the columns in the active pivot, use the column API, eg columnApi.getPivotColumns(), which will return a list of the pivot columns. this will be in order, so if you have many columns, there will be one for each parent you traverse.

Comment: Have you figured out how to setPinnedBottomRowData when pivoting? The code above gets the columnId (e.g. pivot_2), but setPinnedBottomRowData ([{pivot_2:100,...}]) doesn't seem to pay attention to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077503/how-to-display-different-column-data-as-tool-tip-in-ag-grid ... any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did for the pivot_ type of pinned row: I added a custom pinned row renderer to my column, where I expect the aggregated function to show (for me it was for sum and avg). If I change the pivot function I called a refresh on the pinned row to set the new values.

```
pinnedRowCellRenderer: function (render)
            {
                for (var obj_id in render.data)
                {
                    if (obj_id == render.column.colId)
                    {
                        return '<div>' + render.data[obj_id] + '</div>';
                    }
                }
                return '<div></div>';
            }
```

And the result looks like this:
[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEKYE.png)

Hope it helps!