# How to display different column data as tool tip in ag grid pivot mode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

```
var ColDef = [{
    headerName: "colA",
    field: 'colA',
    rowGroup: true
  },
  {
    headerName: "colB",
    field: 'colB',
    pivot: true,
    enablePivot: true
  },
  {
    headerName: "colC",
    field: 'colC',
    rowGroup: true
  },
  {
    field: 'colD',
    aggFunc: 'first',
    valueFormatter: currencyFormatter,
    tooltip: function(params) {
      return (params.valueFormatted);
    },
  },
  {
    field: 'comment'
  },
  {
    field: 'colF'
  }
];
function currencyFormatter(params) {
  return params.value;
}
```

above code is from different question. it works but i want to use different 'comment' field as tool tip to current 'colD' . also this is a group and pivot agGrid,if it is normal grid this is not a problem. I would appreciate any ideas for group and pivot agGrid?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do here, but curious how the data from non pivot mode is going to map with data in pivot mode unless your comment text is same for a single group

Comment: It maps automatically when you put in agGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var ColDef = [{
        headerName: "colA",
        field: 'colA',
        rowGroup: true
      },
      {
        headerName: "colB",
        field: 'colB',
        pivot: true,
        enablePivot: true
      },
      {
        headerName: "colC",
        field: 'colC',
        rowGroup: true
      },
      {
        field: 'colD',
        aggFunc: 'last',
    tooltipValueGetter: commentTooltipValueGetter
      },
      {
        field: 'comment'
      },
      {
        field: 'colF'
      }
    ];


    function commentTooltipValueGetter(params) {
    const colB = params.colDef.pivotKeys[0];
    var model = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(params.rowIndex);
    for (var i = 0; i < model.allLeafChildren.length ; i++) {
        if (model.allLeafChildren[i].data.colB=== colB) {
          return model.allLeafChildren[i].data.comments;
                                                       }
                                             }
  }
```

This is what i had to do for my question. It is combination of answers from @wctiger and @shuts below. So please also refer them for more context

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it actually answers the question. The other answers are beating around the bush

Comment: @shuts13 answer finally made my problem solved, so thats why i made that accepted answer.  Yeah my answer is direct solution of the question.

Comment: You can acknowledge other answer's effort by upvoting but your answer should be the accepted one. If you look at his answer with those multiple updates, I can't really spot the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is good way for the grid to get the data in your scenario then, as your rows and columns are different than original model after pivot.

Maybe you can consider retrieve this information outside of grid. Assume you also want some aggregated information displays in the tooltip, the tooltip function may eventually look like this:

```
tooltip: params => {
  const country = params.node.key;
  const year = params.colDef.pivotKeys[0];
  const athletesWithNumbers = this.state.rowData
    .filter(d => d.year == year)
    .filter(d => d.country === country)
    .filter(d => d.gold > 0)
    .map(d => d.athlete + ': ' + d.gold);
  return athletesWithNumbers.join(', ');
}
```

See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZtVc3Jgvwibuqd4b?preview) for what I am talking about - again, not sure if this is what you want but just an FYI.

Comment: somehow my params.data is undefined

Comment: What do you see in params.node.data? Is your grid displaying rows?

Comment: my params.node.data is undefined. may be i should mention i am doing this on a pivot and on a aggfunc field.i will update question

Comment: rewrite my answer - hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks.this.state ...state is undefined for me somehow

Comment: The example I used is a React version. You should replace the state part with your data source

Comment: Thanks. I got my collection but i don't have the identity field to access in pivot. Lets say colF is identity field above. i cannot get access to colF field directly. Because i need a value colE singular as tool tip which only can be get by using colF field value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214943/discussion-between-nostressdeveloper-and-wctiger).

Answer (score 1):

just use `tooltipValueGetter`

```
{
   field: 'message',
   headerName: 'Message',
   headerTooltip: 'Message',
   width: 110,
   filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
   tooltipValueGetter: (params) =>  `${params.value} some text`
}
```

[image]

or just use the same method for tooltipValueGetter
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I understood

but it also easy

Ag-grid has property `tooltipField` - where you can choose any field from grid

For example here - in the column of 'sport' I am showing tooltip of the previous column

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/zNbMPT5HOB9yqI08

[image]

**OR**

You can easily manipulate with data for each field by `tooltipValueGetter`
with next construction:

```
tooltipValueGetter: function(params) {  
  return `Country: ${params.data.country}, Athlete: ${params.data.athlete}, Sport: ${params.data.sport}`;
},
```

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/zNbMPT5HOB9yqI08

Result:
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Hey Man! I do not understand was is wrong

I just used  your code snippet and my solution

**And it works as you want**

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/zNbMPT5HOB9yqI08
[image]

**UPDATE 3**

A little bit of manipulation and I can get the data

```
{ field: 'gold', aggFunc: 'sum',
    tooltipValueGetter: function(params) {  
    var model = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(params.rowIndex);
    return model.allLeafChildren[0].data.silver;
  },
},
```

The Last:
https://plnkr.co/edit/9qtYjkngKJg6Ihwb?preview

Comment: Hi i  m using angularJS not new angular and i am trying to display different field as tool tip to another field not the same field as tooltip

Comment: Hi i like that idea, but you are doing it in normal grid, mine is a pivot and group  grid and i cannot access data in params when i use pivot. data is getting undefined. and no way to access a column value other than groups and pivot column value

Comment: Hey, thanks for another update. In your Update 2 pivot did not happen, you need to put pivotMode: true in grid options for pivot to work. If you actually change to pivot , data becomed undefined for params

Comment: I just used your snippet

Comment: the new solution is available

Comment: I think this will work. In model.allLeafChildren[0].data.silver. it cannot be 0 all the time here. it has to be dynamic. i am trying to put a dynamic variable there instead of 0 now. otherwise it will be same comment for all values in my example in the question

Comment: when you get node by index by method `getDisplayedRowAtIndex` - there is only one current item -- that why I am using the first item ([0]) always

Comment: oh ok for me i have multiple items.  so for each value of colD in question i will have a different comment in same row.

Comment: finally succeeded in what i needed. please see my answer. ofcourse with your help and also @wctiger below. Now i don't know which one i should mark as answer. Yours or mine. But mine is mostly your logic with little change for my scenario

Comment: Probably without my answer  you could not complete the task.
Originally you would like to show tooltip from one column to another in pivot mode. I did it. and it covered 90% of your task

Comment: Thanks. Marked yours as answer